# UIWebView calling custom method?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am having trouble in calling a method that I defined screenCap by a UIWebView. Basically, I have two UIWebView declared: `firstWebView` and `secondWebView`.

I ran a javascript to extract some HTML loaded by the firstWebView and display it to the `secondWebView` by calling `[secondWebView loadHTMLString: extractString baseURL:nil];`

What I want to do is after `secondWebView` is loaded, I want to call
    [secondWebView screenCap: self];

The screenCap method is defined by:

```
-(void) screenCap: (UIWebView *)webView; {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.frame.size);
    [webView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    viewImage; = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    theImageView.image = viewImage;
    NSLog(@"write Image done!");
```

I, however got a warning "UIWebView may not respond to '-screenCap' and of course the screenCap never got called. can anyone direct me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in the code of the ScreenCap method.

But instead of doing

> [secondWebView screenCap: self];

write

> [self screenCap:secondWebView];